# Looking to get counts of items within ArrayType column without using Explode

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**NOTE: I'm working with Spark 2.4**

Here is my dataset:

**df**

```
col
[1,3,1,4]
[1,1,1,2]
```

I'd like to essentially get a value_counts of the values in the array. The results df wou

**df_upd**

```
col
[{1:2},{3:1},{4:1}]
[{1:3},{2:1}]
```

I know I can do this by exploding `df` and then taking a group by but I'm wondering if I can do this without exploding.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the explode?  A simple udf would work but wouldn't be as efficient as explode then groupby I would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using a udf that outputs the result as a MapType.  It expects integer values in your arrays (easily changed) and to return integer counts.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

df = sc.parallelize([([1, 2, 3, 3, 1],),([4, 5, 6, 4, 5],),([2, 2, 2],),([3, 3],)]).toDF(['arrays'])

df.show()

+---------------+
|         arrays|
+---------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 3, 1]|
|[4, 5, 6, 4, 5]|
|      [2, 2, 2]|
|         [3, 3]|
+---------------+

from collections import Counter

@F.udf(returnType=T.MapType(T.IntegerType(), T.IntegerType(), valueContainsNull=False))
def count_elements(array):
    return dict(Counter(array))

df.withColumn('counts', count_elements(F.col('arrays'))).show(truncate=False)

+---------------+------------------------+
|arrays         |counts                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 3, 1]|[1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 2]|
|[4, 5, 6, 4, 5]|[4 -> 2, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1]|
|[2, 2, 2]      |[2 -> 3]                |
|[3, 3]         |[3 -> 2]                |
+---------------+------------------------+
```